# Code is providing a row of data but not formatting it as table

Tags: shortcode, database, code, table

I am using the following code:

```
function seconddb() {
    global $seconddb;
    $seconddb = new wpdb('username','password','g3boat5_G3_Genba','localhost');
}
add_action('init','seconddb');
// add the shortcode [pontoon-table], tell WP which function to call
add_shortcode( 'pontoon-table', 'pontoon_table_shortcode' );

// add the shortcode [pontoon-table], tell WP which function to call
add_shortcode( 'pontoon-table', 'pontoon_table_shortcode' );

// this function generates the shortcode output
function pontoon_table_shortcode( $args ) {

    global $seconddb;
    // Shortcodes RETURN content, so store in a variable to return
    $content = '<table>';
    $content .= '</tr><th>Week Beginning</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th><th>Weekly Total</th><th>Previous Week Totals</th></tr>';
    $results = $seconddb->get_results( ' SELECT * FROM seconddb_PontoonBoats_LineOne_2Log' );
    foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
        $content = '<tr>';
        // Modify these to match the database structure
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->{'Week Beginning'} . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Monday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Tuesday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Wednesday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Thursday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Friday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Saturday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Sunday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->{'Weekly Total'} . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->{'Previous Week Totals'} . '</td>';
        $content .= '</tr>';
    }
    $content .= '</table>';

    // return the table
    return $content;
}
```

[image]

So that is the correct data being pulled from the database but as you can see it is not being displayed in the table as coded. What is my next step to try and get this to render in a nicely constructed table?

Furthermore...if someone knows, can you explain how I can put a place on this page to to select a date and then the data pulled from the database be from that date?

I am trying to do everything in shortcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not displayed as table, because you don't return correct HTML code. Let's take a look at your code (I've put comments at end of incorrect lines):

```
$content = '<table>';
$content .= '</tr><th>Week Beginning</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th><th>Weekly Total</th><th>Previous Week Totals</th></tr>';  // <- here you open TR with </tr>, so it's already incorrect
$results = $seconddb->get_results( ' SELECT * FROM seconddb_PontoonBoats_LineOne_2Log' );
foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
    $content = '<tr>';  // <- here you overwrite previous value of $content with string '<tr>'
    // Modify these to match the database structure
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->{'Week Beginning'} . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->Monday . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->Tuesday . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->Wednesday . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->Thursday . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->Friday . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->Saturday . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->Sunday . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->{'Weekly Total'} . '</td>';
    $content .= '<td>' . $row->{'Previous Week Totals'} . '</td>';
    $content .= '</tr>';
}
$content .= '</table>';
```

So your function returns something like this, if there are no rows (it's incorrect HTML):

```
<table>
    </tr><th>Week Beginning</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th><th>Weekly Total</th><th>Previous Week Totals</th></tr>
</table>
```

And something like this, if there are any rows found:

```
<tr>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->{'Week Beginning'}></td>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->Monday></td>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->Tuesday></td>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->Wednesday></td>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->Thursday></td>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->Friday></td>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->Saturday></td>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->Sunday></td>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->{'Weekly Total'}></td>
    <td><VALUE FOR: $row->{'Previous Week Totals'}></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here's the fixed version of that function:

```
function pontoon_table_shortcode( $args ) {

    global $seconddb;
    // Shortcodes RETURN content, so store in a variable to return
    $content = '<table>';
    $content .= '<tr><th>Week Beginning</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th><th>Weekly Total</th><th>Previous Week Totals</th></tr>';
    $results = $seconddb->get_results( ' SELECT * FROM seconddb_PontoonBoats_LineOne_2Log' );
    foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
        $content .= '<tr>';
        // Modify these to match the database structure
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->{'Week Beginning'} . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Monday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Tuesday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Wednesday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Thursday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Friday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Saturday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->Sunday . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->{'Weekly Total'} . '</td>';
        $content .= '<td>' . $row->{'Previous Week Totals'} . '</td>';
        $content .= '</tr>';
    }
    $content .= '</table>';

    // return the table
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: ```` $content = '<tr>'; ```` should be ```` $content .= '<tr>'; ```` Thank you so much! Typo on my part!

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code, replace this part

```
    $content .= '</tr><th>Week Beginning</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th><th>Weekly Total</th><th>Previous Week Totals</th></tr>';
```

with this

```
 $content .= '<tr><th>Week Beginning</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th><th>Weekly Total</th><th>Previous Week Totals</th></tr>';
```

and this

```
foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
    $content = '<tr>';
....
....
}
```

with this

```
foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
    $content .= '<tr>';
....
....
}
```

and see the result.

To make it a nice looking table, add some style through CSS.

I hope this will help.

UPDATE:
@Krzysiek Dróżdż answer explains in detail what is wrong with your code.